# How to land sleeping armies from a transport onto a shore in Empire?

Tags: vms-empire

The game I am referring to is called Empire or [VMS Empire](https://libregamewiki.org/VMS_Empire). It works in terminal on Unix-like systems, particularly on [Ubuntu](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/man6/empire.6.html). It is an early derivative of the [Classic Empire](http://www.classicempire.com/history.html) from 1970s, which inspired Sid Meier's Civilization.

The question is:

When I move armies into a transport and then press "S" (sentry/sleep) for those armies, how to wake them up after the transport has arrived to a peaceful shore?